# Moving multiple Web.config sections to the same separate file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

In ASP.NET MVC 4, I know you can move sections of the Web.config file to other files by pointing the `configSource` attribute of those sections at the relevant files. I also know that you can more the `appSettings` section by using the `file` attribute to point at the correct file. However, as far as I can see these methods limit you to one section per file.

What I'm trying to do is move all settings that the end user can edit to one file, so that we can tell the user that this file can be tweaked, but any other `.config` file should be left well alone. Unfortunately, if I move (for example) the `appSettings` and `connectionStrings` sections to the same file, I get errors.

- If I drop them straight into the file, I get an error about having multiple root XML elements. Fair enough.
- If I wrap the sections in `<configuration>` tags like in the main Web.config file, I get an error that says "The format of a configSource file must be an element containing the name of the section", which suggests that the limit of one section per file is pretty strict.

Is there a way around this? Can I put multiple sections in one file?

Comment: I'm having the same question, expecting someone to solve this